# Administrator of Office 2010 OneNote Notebook

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-onenote-2010

I've created a shared Notebook on our server for myself and two colleagues who are working on the same project. It's password protected, so that the three of us can edit/brainstorm before the notes are shown to the team leader. I would like to know if there is a way to set permissions so that the team leader has read-only access, the people involved in the project have read/write access, and I have pseudo "administrator" type access, where I'm the only one who can rearrange the structure, remove permissions, etc?

I have been through the sharing options, and it does not seem to possible, but I might have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Office Web Apps? It looks pretty feature complete, and they have OneNote on there. You can use it for free, and sharing is pretty cool, too. Check it out! :-)

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps-help/share-a-spreadsheet-document-presentation-or-notebook-in-skydrive-HA101820121.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, but not really what I had in mind, as we all work in the same office and access the same server.

Comment: Fair point--I'd probably not be able to use that solution at work, either. You may want to look into using SharePoint to host the file, but that may make it difficult for you and your teammates to edit the file simultaneously.